# Visual studio 2012 project - Not able to load 'Newtonsoft.Json'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, json.net, csproj

On running a windows phone project in VS 2012, I was getting this error:

```
    {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at MobileConnection.SSCClient.SSCConnection.GetHostNameAndPort()
   at MobileConnection.SSCClient.SSCConnection.InitializeSSCConnection(Boolean runningState)}
```

The corresponding entries in .csproj file is:

```
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11\lib\sl4-windowsphone71\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And, in packages.config:

```
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="wp80" />
```

I debugged it for a while, re-installed the newtonsoft.json package through nuget.
**But the solution that worked for me is setting the 'private' property to 'True'.**

Updated entry in .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11\lib\sl4-windowsphone71\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
   <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I am not able to understand how it worked or what the issue was. The description on msdn documentation didn't help much either http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb629388.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the program, it pulls in dlls from the output directory.  Originally, `Newtonsoft.Json` wasn't being copied to the output directory, but by specifying `Private` to `True`, you told Visual Studio to copy the `Newtonsoft.Json` dll to the output folder along with your program.

For completeness, the documentation on Private:

> Optional boolean. Specifies whether the reference should be copied to the output folder. This attribute matches the Copy Local property of the reference that's in the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: ok, that explains the issue. But I haven't explicitly specified this 'private' for other dlls in my project, and they are working just fine (even newtonsoft.json was working fine before). Any reason why it would work without setting 'private' to 'True'?

Comment: Normally when nuget adds it, it should add it as private by default.  I'm assuming that at some point it was accidentally converted to non-private (perhaps someone accidentally set "Copy Local" false in the project properties?).