# Could Not load NewtonSoft.JSON after deploying MVC app to Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've deployed a MVC 4.5 web site [here](http://dxchange.azurewebsites.net)

However, when I view the site in browser after deployment, I have to turn custom errors off to see the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I ensured that CopyLocal is set to True for the DLL in my References folder.  What other changes need to be made for a successful deployment?

Comment: Check what package actually contains (either by opening package itself, or just looking into local build folder). While I think "copy local" should be enough sometimes you'd need to look into build logs to figure out why some assemblies are not copied during build...

Comment: When you say opening the package, is that through package manager, or another window?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know - I've build Azure stuff about 2 years ago - so not sure how to actually get it with current tools (I'd expect one be available locally in build folders).

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well and I've taken all of the same steps and it's killing me. I've also deployed a default application and it gets the same error. My hope is that this is something wrong with Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same issue today and I'm not completely sure what I did to fix it. So I'll try giving a detailed walk through of my process.

1. I tried deploying a default app out of VS13 and it was too bombing with this message. FAIL.
2. I then removed the Newtonsoft.Json assembly and manually added the 5.0.6 version I needed. I also made sure CopyToLocal was set to true. FAIL. My sadness grows.
3. I enabled NuGet Package Restore. FAIL. My sadness turns to anger.
4. I deleted my Azure site in a fit of rage, recreated it, and the republished out again. **SUCCESS!!!**

So, the only logical(ish) answer I think I can give is to delete your Azure website, recreate it, and then publish again.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I will try the same. Will edit question or post an answer thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by redirecting the assembly version from 0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0 to 6.0.0.0

by adding a depententAssembly in Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <!-- Add these 4 lines to Web.config, under runtime/assemblyBinding -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- End of copy -->

    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<configuration>
```

You will find other dependentAssemblies there too, like System.Web.Mvc, WebGrease.

The newest version of Newtonsoft.Json is now 6.0.3. You may have to increase 6.0.0.0 later. Find the current newest version by looking at the version in the Solution Explorer. References -> Newton.Json -> (right click -> Properties) -> Version in the Property view

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure CopyLocal is true, then the only other possibility is that you have project reference to a different assembly version than what's listed in your packages.config. Make sure the DLL version matches the version in the packages.config.

Comment: packages.config shows version 5.0.8  I removed the DLL reference to version 4.5.0.0.  I get a clean build, but error persists.

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999777/visual-studio-2012-project-not-able-to-load-newtonsoft-json be the cause?

Comment: I've checked all of this as well. Also, I deployed a default application to azure and it gives me the same error. Could this possibly be an azure issue?